# I keep getting an indexerror and don't know why

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to build a brute force password cracker (for educational purposes) but my code keeps returning an `indexerror` that says list index out of range on line 19. I do not know why this is happening. I would suspect it has something to do with the list insert with variables in it but I don't know.

```
import random
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

username = ("")

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("site")

chars = ["0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z","a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"]
password = ["a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a"]
list_index1 = 0
list_index2 = 0
list_insert = 0
list_pos = 0

while(driver.current_url != "logged in site"):
    password[list_index2] = chars[list_index1]
    driver.find_element_by_id("j_username").send_keys(username)
    driver.find_element_by_id("j_password").send_keys(password)
    driver.find_element_by_name("login").click()
    list_index1 += 1
    print (password)
if (list_index1 == 61):
    listinsert += 1
    list_pos += 1
    list_index2.insert(list_pos, list_insert)
    list_index1 = 0
print (list_index1)
```

Comment: you can start with `import pdb` and put after the `while...` `pdb.set_trace()`.
and assuming you never check `list_index1` vs `len(chars)` and `list_index2` vs `len(password)` I'd guess you can start there...

Comment: Usually this happens when you assume something returned a list and try to loop over it without checking. Basically a search for Selenium should get you dozens of duplicates for this question on the first page.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Oops, I see how the url is supposed to change now. It's when it logs in successfully, I get it. I have also realized that you probably just need to indent the if-statement below the while loop to fix your issue, since it looks like that's where you were trying to implement safeguards against the index error. Right now the if-statement is never reached inside the loop.

Old, completely wrong answer: The most immediate problem is that your while loop is infinite. Unless the url changes automatically after a couple seconds, nothing ever manually changes the url you're on and nothing breaks from the loop. Because of this, you just keep incrementing `list_index1` forever until it's eventually larger than `chars`, causing the index error.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues in your code.

Firstly, within your while loop, you keep incrementing the value of `list_index1` and assign `chars[list_index1]` to `password[list_index2]`. This means as the loop continues, your `password` follows the following pattern:

```
["0","a","a","a","a","a","a","a"]
["1","a","a","a","a","a","a","a"]
.
.
["z","a","a","a","a","a","a","a"]
```

Once you hit `z`, `list_index1` will go out of range in the next iteration unless the correct password lies in one of the strings above.
Your `if` condition is outside the loop, so it does not reset the value of `list_index1` back to 0.

Secondly, you might also want to pay attention to the following line:

```
list_index2.insert(list_pos, list_insert).
```

`list_index2` is an integer in your code. Here you are treating it as a list.